# Detecting Ctrl-<Number> in GLUT

Tags: glut

I use GLUT to handle keyboard input for [Bitfighter](http://bitfighter.org).  I've built a nice little keyboard event abstraction layer, which works great for most things, but I've run up against a few frustrating limitations.

For example, when Ctrl is pressed, the number keys, plus, minus, and the quote key don't seem to trigger the glutKeyboardFunc() callback.

I realize that GLUT is very limited in some ways, but I was wondering if anyone knows if it is possible to detect the number keys or plus/minus when Ctrl is pressed.

I would consider switching to FreeGLUT if it helped work around this limitation.

Comment: please do post the answer when you find it...

Comment: I've run into this issue too, on Ubuntu 9.10 (GNOME). I get key events for ctrl-1, but not ctrl-2, ctrl-3, others. What could be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a lot of research on this, and concluded it simply doesn't work.

For this reason, and other frustrations, we eventually ported our code from GLUT to SDL.